# Android: Use of MapFragment within one of a number of Fragments

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-nested-fragment

I searched and searched, no one answer it in totality.

I have a project that needs to use the new MapFragment within one of a number of Fragments in an Android project.

I have it so far like a FB mobile app.  It shows a menu on the left and user can select an item and shows a fragment.  So far, I searched and searched.  No complete and workable answer.

I like to see sample code and/or sample project that can display the new Google MapFragment within a fragment of many fragments in an Android app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are asking for a fair bit of code. What part of using `getChildFragmentManager()` is not working for you?

Comment: I just did some research on getChildFragmentManager(), you have to use IMPORT android.support.v4.app.Fragment and others like that instead of using IMPORT android.app.Fragment and others.  There's a lot of inconsistencies with the IMPORT statements and their supported functions.  I am developing my app using this Project here: https://github.com/lexs/android-delicious  TRYING to incorporate MapFragment inside one of the many Fragments in that app.  Please provide some help in editing the project to allow that if u can constructively help. Tnx. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I just did some research on getChildFragmentManager(), you have to use IMPORT android.support.v4.app.Fragment and others like that instead of using IMPORT android.app.Fragment and others

Not necessarily, though [`getChildFragmentManager()` was only added to the native `Fragment` implementation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) in API Level 17.

You are welcome to use `SupportMapFragment` for use with the Android Support package's backport of fragments. That should allow you to use `getChildFragmentManager()` with Maps V2.

Comment: All these different stuff is ridiculous.  I changed a fragment file to extend SupportMapFragment and the whole thing cries foul.  I don't know what you are referring what to use with what.  Please if anyone kind enough to know how to update that sample project I listed above to use MapFragment correctly and workable within one of the Fragments, please do so to help everyone whose curious about the new poorly documented MapFragments. tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding SupportMapFragment programmatically works. In your fragment implementation:

```
...
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
...

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // add fragment 
    mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.game_map_container, mMapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    // add a marker
    map = mMapFragment.getMap();

    if (map != null) {
        // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(target));
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(target, 10));
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "map is not available");
    }
}
```

Actually, the idea is stolen from [Initialize MapFragment programmatically with Maps API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733299/initialize-mapfragment-programmatically-with-maps-api-v2)