# Get GoogleMap from ViewPager's fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to get `GoogleMap` object from a `Fragment`, which is on the second page of `ViewPager`, whose contents are given with `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

My `ViewPager` consist of two pages: an ordinary layout, and a Google map.

I can access to the first layout doing this:

```
View tempView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication())
                .inflate(R.layout.start_activity, null);
tempTextView = (TextView) tempView.findViewById(R.id.timer);
```

Everything is OK here. But I also want to access Google maps.
When the map was in a separate activity, I could get `GoogleMap` object doing this:

```
map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

But now the above line returns `null`

The question is **how to get `GoogleMap` object from fragment now?**

They suggest doing this (some people say this works), but it doesn't take effect for me:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
      .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":1")).getMap();
```

I'm providing the code [here](http://pastebin.com/U7nuyLck).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733299/initialize-mapfragment-programmatically-with-maps-api-v2), but will post here too for other users to see the code and not get stuck for weeks like I did.

**MyPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    final LatLng    YEREVAN = new LatLng(40.181, 44.513);

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context)
    {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return new MyFragment();
            case 1:
                return MyMapFragment.newInstance(YEREVAN);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return context.getString(R.string.start).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return context.getString(R.string.map).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MyMapFragment.java**

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment
{
    private LatLng  latLon;

    public MyMapFragment()
    {
        super();
    }

    public static MyMapFragment newInstance(LatLng position)
    {
        MyMapFragment frag = new MyMapFragment();
        frag.latLon = position;
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        initMap();
        return v;
    }

    private void initMap()
    {
        UiSettings settings = getMap().getUiSettings();
        settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        settings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

        getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLon, 16));
        getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLon).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `MyFragmentPagerAdapter` doesn't use `SupportMapFragment`s, but only adds `MyFragment`s.
You should change its `getItem` function to something like this:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new MyFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new MySupportMapFragment();
        break;
    }
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(MyFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

For that you have to implement your own type `MySupportMapFragment` where you load your layout, similar with what you did with `MyFragment`.

Then you can call your SupportMapFragment directly from the `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Like:

```
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = 
    (SupportMapFragment) mMyFragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
map = supportMapFragment.getMap();
```

Once added to the adapter, you should get the SupportMapFragment you are expecting.

Comment: I get `ClassCastException`: MyFragment cannot be cast to SupportMapFragment. Are you sure the `getItem()` method is working properly? I've left it untouched, it was created automatically by android.

Comment: I see. Well, `getItem()` returns a `Fragment`, and I just wanted to downcast it to `SupportMapFragment`. But with a look at your code, it seems you never create a SupportMapFragment, but only a normal Fragment with a view with a map. You should change your method `getItem(int position)` in `MyFragmentPagerAdapter`, so that it returns a Fragment at position 0, and a SupportMapFragment at position 1. I will edit my answer and show you in a minute...

Comment: "For that you have to implement your own type MySupportMapFragment where you load your layout, similar with what you did with MyFragment"   -> should the `MySupportMapFragment` extend `Fragment` or `MapFragment`? 
If `Fragment`, then it's useless, because I inflate my view checking the fragment attributes.
If `MapFragment`, then adapter's `getItem()` complains, because it returns `Fragment` instead of `MapFragment`. What should I do?

Comment: `MySupportMapFragment` should implement `SupportMapFragment`. So, for case (1) your MyFragmentPagerAdapter returns a SupportMapFragment. Since SupportMapFragment extends Fragment, it shouldn't complain. Then, if you say `(SupportMapFragment) mMyFragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(1);` you should be able to cast to a SupportMapFragment.

Comment: I've changed my code. So now the `ViewPager` has only 1 page (the map). Look at the code above, please, I've edited the post. Still the `gMap` is `null`. What is incorrect here?