# Android google map custom marker

Tags: android, google-maps

Am using custom markers for my google map. All the marker images are getting from server and with help of lazy loading i can display . The issue is that  if the maker is set before image downloading completed it never update the map with new image.

Any help would be appreciated

```
public class ROverViewRender extends DefaultClusterRenderer<RItem> {

    private IconGenerator mIconGenerator;
    private IconGenerator mClusterIconGenerator;
    private RImageView mImageView;
    private RImageView mImageVieStar;
    private ImageView mClusterImageView;
    private Context context;
    private ClusterManager<RItem> mClusterManager;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public ROverViewRender(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<RItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);

        this.mClusterManager=clusterManager;
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        this.context=context;
        mClusterIconGenerator=new IconGenerator(context);
        View clustorIcon = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.clustor_icon, null);
        mClusterIconGenerator.setContentView(clustorIcon);
        mIconGenerator=new IconGenerator(context);
        View markerIcon = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_icon, null);
        mIconGenerator.setContentView(markerIcon);
        mImageView=(RImageView)markerIcon.findViewById(R.id.marker_image);
        mImageVieStar=(RImageView)markerIcon.findViewById(R.id.marker_route_rating);
        mClusterImageView=(NetworkImageView)clustorIcon.findViewById(R.id.cluster_image);

        imageLoader=VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(final RItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

        setMarkerImage(item,markerOptions);
         Bitmap icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
         markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));


    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<RItem> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
         Drawable drawable =context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        mClusterImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
         Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
         markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
    }

     @Override
     protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {
         // Always render clusters.
         return cluster.getSize() > 1;
     }
     @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(RItem clusterItem, Marker marker) {
         RLog.e("Invoked the ....>>>>>");
    //   setMarkerImage(clusterItem);

    }

     private void setMarkerImage(RItem item,final MarkerOptions markerOptions){
         RLog.e("Image setter invoked..."+item.getMarkerUrl());
         mImageView.setImageUrl(item.getMarkerUrl(), imageLoader);
         imageLoader.get(item.getMarkerUrl(), new ImageListener() {

                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 //   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_error); // set an error image if the download fails
                }

                public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
                    RLog.e("Image download completed...");
                    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                        mImageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());


                    } 
                }
            });
     }
}
```

Comment: you want to change the icon of marker when image is finish downloading?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733299/initialize-mapfragment-programmatically-with-maps-api-v2

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: yes ,but the problem is the image is updating during the second time rendering only :(

Comment: what is `RImageView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Fixed. The google map marker have setIcon method which help us to update the icon. so whenever i got the callback from image downloader i will update it through setIcon method . So far no issues ,working perfectly fine.