# Google map v2 getting my location

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, google-maps-api-2

it gives me error at runtime shutting down VM

here is logcat

```
06-12 13:37:52.844: I/u(6937): Making Creator dynamically
06-12 13:37:53.675: I/Google Maps Android API(6937): Google Play services client version: 4452000
06-12 13:37:53.705: I/Google Maps Android API(6937): Google Play services package version: 4452034
06-12 13:37:55.287: I/fpp(6937): Making Creator dynamically
06-12 13:37:55.287: I/Google Maps Android API(6937): Google Play services client version: 4452000
06-12 13:37:55.507: D/dalvikvm(6937): GC_CONCURRENT freed 882K, 10% free 10018K/11043K, paused 28ms+13ms
06-12 13:37:56.608: D/AndroidRuntime(6937): Shutting down VM
06-12 13:37:56.608: W/dalvikvm(6937): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aaa210)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appmap.appmap/com.appmap.appmap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at com.appmap.appmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
06-12 13:37:56.688: E/AndroidRuntime(6937):     ... 11 more
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap gmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);






    /*if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }*/
}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `gMap` is null. Post `activity_main.xml` and the fragment layout if you have one.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

Comment: post the both the layouts by editing your post and name them. is it `activity_main.xml` or `framgent_main.xml`??

Comment: How to intialise the map before using it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13734470/637545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are not intializing map in your code

Do this in your OnCreate Method

```
support_map_fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googlemap = support_map_fragment.getMap();

        googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


        googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googlemap.getMyLocation();
```

Comment: Open Declaration Fragment android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.findFragmentById(int arg0)


Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

i have done that but it gives me a error like this as mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to `initialized` your `Google Map Object` like so

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
GoogleMap gmap = fm.getMap();
```

Your app crashed because you're `gmap` is `NULL` at this location

```
 gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

As per your comment you should change this

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

with

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: my maps work fine but when i want to know my location with gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); it gives error ....

can u fix this code to show my location ?? as mentioned above i dont know where i am mistaking