# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #176: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried every thing but still it crashes . anyone please help me. This is my code for map.
I successfuly implemented map with fragment activity and supportfragment(as individual project). but when i tried to implement in our main project which was a fragment rather than a fragment activity, i tried using fragment manager etc but all in vain :(

I did everything i saw in the other posts here like using mapview , try catch for layout inflate..but nothing worked

My complete code is very lengthy. i wanted to implement a map view/support fragment in that code..so i am writing only the part where map is implemented. and where issue occurs. I this there is some problem in layout. because in inflate layout crash happens every time.

```
      public class EventFragment extends Fragment{


               @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (rootView != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(rootView);
        }

        try {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.workspace_event_fragment_layout, container, false);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
         return rootView;               
    }
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        mapView = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapView == null) {
            mapView = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapView).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if (theMap == null) {
            theMap = mapView.getMap();
            theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)));
        }
    }
```

in xml

```
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

this fragment is in between scroll layouts->linear layouts 
i am getting error:

```
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #176: Error inflating class fragment
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at com.cordiant.cordiantlearn.workspace.WorkspaceEventFragment.onCreateView(WorkspaceEventFragment.java:204)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:651)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2586)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
07-22 16:37:33.845: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2189)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1352)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1535)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment did not create a view.
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
07-22 16:37:33.850: W/System.err(21217):    ... 51 more
```

My Complete Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/greyBG"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/greyBG"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/workspace_eventTab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/workspace_profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_prof_loading" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/workspace_event_subject_TV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Subject"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/workspace_event_subject_ET"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:hint="Subject" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/workspace_event_expand_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/workspace_desc_event_TV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/workspace_desc_event_ET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="Description" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/allDay_checkbox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="All Day" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/workspace_event_startDate_TV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Start Date"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/workspace_event_startDatePicker_btn"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:textColor="@color/calenderGreen"
                        android:textSize="21sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/workspace_event_startTimePicker_btn"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:textColor="@color/actionbar_bg_color"
                        android:textSize="21sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/workspace_event_startDate_ET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="Start Date" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/workspace_event_endDate_TV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="End Date"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/workspace_event_endDatePicker_btn"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:textColor="@color/calenderGreen"
                        android:textSize="21sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/workspace_event_endTimePicker_btn"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:textColor="@color/actionbar_bg_color"
                        android:textSize="21sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/workspace_event_endDate_ET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="End Date" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/workspace_event_location_TV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Location"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

                <com.cordiant.cordiantlearn.workspace.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/workspace_event_location_ET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="Location" 
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"/>

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/workspace_event_room_TV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Room"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/workspace_event_room_ET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:hint="Room" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view_for_mapview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Invitees"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightGray" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioBtn_pg_event_layout"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:text="Performance Group"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                        android:text="Invite one or more Performance Groups to this Event"
                        android:textColor="@color/gray" />

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/atv_pg_event_workspace"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/lv_pg_event_fragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="visible" >
                    </ListView>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioBtn_people_event_layout"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:text="Specific People"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                        android:text="Invite one or more People to this Event"
                        android:textColor="@color/gray" />

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/atv_people_event_workspace"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/lv_people_event_fragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="visible" >
                    </ListView>
                </RadioGroup>

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/restrictedAccessCheckbox_event"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Restricted Access"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <CheckedTextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="* If it is marked as 'Restricted Access', then it will be accessible only within the Performance Groups or Specific People to which it has been shared."/>

                <CheckedTextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="* The Content with restricted access will not come up in the Search results if the User is not part of that Content."/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/workspace_createBtn_event"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/browse_button_drawable"
                        android:text="Create Event"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/workspace_closeBtn_event"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/browse_button_drawable"
                        android:text="Close"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you are saying everything  :)

Comment: but i dont know to solve this :(

Comment: actually ur view is not created properly :) take a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html

Comment: i have updated my layout..please check this and tell me where i am wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved:

use `<FrameLayout/>` instead of `<Fragment/>`

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1.03"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:id="@+id/mapwhere" />
```

and

```
public class WhereFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
  View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.where, null, false); 
  initilizeMap();
  return root;
 }

private void initilizeMap()
 {
  mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapwhere);
  if (mSupportMapFragment == null) {
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mapwhere, mSupportMapFragment).commit();
     }
  if (mSupportMapFragment != null)
  {
   googleMap = mSupportMapFragment.getMap();
   if (googleMap != null)
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener()
    {
     @Override
     public void onMapClick(LatLng point)
     {
      //TODO: your onclick stuffs
     }
    });
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not supported. See [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments). This is from the developer documentation:

> **Note**: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a . Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.

What it basically says is as follows. Consider a class **MyClass**

```
public class MyClass extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myclass, container,
            false);

    return view;
}
}
```

The layout file **fragment_myclass** cannot contain **< fragment/>** tag as an element.

Comment: so what to do to add a map??

Comment: @AndroidBeginner you extend fragmentActivity and put the <fragment> tag of map in the layout referenced by that xml. Or try approach of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733299/initialize-mapfragment-programmatically-with-maps-api-v2

Comment: Still same crash.. :(