# Add a marker to a dynamic Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, marker, supportmapfragment

I am develoeping an app that shows a map with specified LatLng values.
The map fragment is dynamic (Not R.id.map)

When i'm trying to add a marker to the specified location (That i'm getting from Google Places API JSON request) i'm getting a null pointer exepction.

this is the code:

```
        @Override
public void initMap(int position, long id, ListView listView) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PlacesContract.Places.LAT));
    String lng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PlacesContract.Places.LNG));
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PlacesContract.Places.NAME));
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng));
    GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();

    options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    options.camera(CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

    mapFragment = GoogleMapFragment.newInstance(options);
    mUIGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(name));
    if (findViewById(R.id.map_container) != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, mapFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.listview_container, mapFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

}
}
```

GoogleMapFragment Class =

```
public class GoogleMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

private static final String SUPPORT_MAP_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapOptions";

public static interface OnGoogleMapFragmentListener {
    void onMapReady(GoogleMap map);
}

public static GoogleMapFragment newInstance() {
    GoogleMapFragment fragment = new GoogleMapFragment();
    return fragment;
}

public static GoogleMapFragment newInstance(GoogleMapOptions options) {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putParcelable(SUPPORT_MAP_BUNDLE_KEY, options);

    GoogleMapFragment fragment = new GoogleMapFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallback = (OnGoogleMapFragmentListener) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().getClass().getName() + " must implement OnGoogleMapFragmentListener");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater arg0, ViewGroup arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    Fragment fragment = getParentFragment();
    return v;
}

private OnGoogleMapFragmentListener mCallback;
```

}

Error Log :

```
03-01 13:40:36.069  17720-17720/com.fragments.ofir.nearby E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.fragments.ofir.nearby, PID: 17720
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
        at com.fragments.ofir.nearby.MainActivity.initMap(MainActivity.java:184)
        at com.fragments.ofir.nearby.fragments.ResultsFragment.onItemClick(ResultsFragment.java:113)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1186)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3095)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4038)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: are you getting latLng correctly(not null) ? can you post your error logs?

Comment: @Sadiq i have added the error log to the question,and yes i'm getting the right LatLng,without the addmarker() method the map is working great.

Comment: @Ofir Can you please tell which line is 184?

Comment: mapFragment.getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)); @Arshdeep_somal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Making new instance of SupportMapFragment, you should try extending SupportMapFragment class. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733299/initialize-mapfragment-programmatically-with-maps-api-v2).

Comment: Still getting null pointer..
All work exepct the Marker.
I added the GoogleMapFragment custom class to the original question.

Comment: I have managed to do it by using Global variables,and add the markers on the OnMapReady callback.
There isn't a better way to do that?