# How to programmatically create a Fragment Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

```
layContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_survey_list);

  TextView textQuestion;

            textQuestion = new TextView(this);
            textQuestion.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textQuestion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            textQuestion.setPadding(8,35,3,0);
            textQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textQuestion.setText(surveyS.get(s));
            layContent.addView(textQuestion);
```

I have already made a textview programmatically and I want to make one programmatically for fragment google map like Textview. How can I do that ?

```
<fragment
           android:id="@+id/map"
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:visibility="gone"/>
```

My question is this Googlemap will array in layContent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add map fragment programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697884/how-to-add-map-fragment-programmatically)

Comment: but i want to make like TextView how ? because this is array

Answer (score 0):

`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();
fragmentTransaction.add (R.id.myFrame, myFrag);
fragmentTransaction.commit ();`

check this link: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/programmatically-working-with-android-fragments/

Comment: how to create fragment google map without XML? i need that